# “TypeError: cannot read property ‘save’ of undefined" - Function to draw on specified canvas

Tags: typescript, html5-canvas

I've written a draw function to draw sprites on different canvases depending on the context I pass in:

```
public draw = (canvasContext): void => {
    canvasContext.save();
    canvasContext.translate(this.x, this.y);
    canvasContext.drawImage(this.atlas.image,
        this.atlas.frames[this.imageName].x, this.atlas.frames[this.imageName].y,
        this.atlas.frames[this.imageName].w, this.atlas.frames[this.imageName].h,
        0, 0,
        this.atlas.frames[this.imageName].w, this.atlas.frames[this.imageName].h);
    canvasContext.restore();
}
```

The code operates fine, whenever I call the method I pass in the context of the canvas I want the sprite to be drawn on and it works. When I open up the console it says “TypeError: cannot read property ‘save’ of undefined" and I'm not really sure how to fix this, would I have to define canvasContext outside of this code somewhere? Unsure how I'd do that.

Comment: How are you calling `draw`? The error suggests however you're doing it, you're not passing anything into it (or what you're passing in has the value `undefined`).

Comment: So for example I have `background.draw(ctx);` and I have ctx defined with `let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;`

Comment: You are using typescript, why don't you type the parameter. This is the exact reason for using static typing. (I can't believe I'm saying this :-) ) - if you type it as `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, TJ's point will become clear.

Comment: @LJones: When do you ever assign something to `ctx`? From what you've shown above, `ctx` will have the value `undefined`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn so what you were suggesting was to type canvasContext so I'd have `public draw = (canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void => ...`? I'm still struggling to understand why the error persists (sorry I'm new to this), I don't know why my ctx would be undefined because in `window.onload` I have `ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");` but I'm guessing that has nothing to do with it? It's frustrating because the code works as intended it just chucks an undefined error and I can't understand why

Comment: And you have absolutely verified line number and stack trace of error origin?

Comment: Yeah it's saying "TypeError: canvasContext is undefined" and redirects me to this function, I'm not sure what I'd have to do to fix that

Comment: @LJones - it is the stack trace that is most important at this point. You need to validate "which call" to that function is sending an undefined context. Do you call this function within an event handler someplace?

Comment: And to catch up a bit, YES, I recommend you do: `public draw = (canvasContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D): void => ...` : This helps you find the problem at compile time rather than run time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest debugging like this:

```
if(!canvasContext) {
  debugger;
}
canvasContext.save();
```

By adding the lines above `canvasContext.save()`, it will pause JS execution whenever canvasContext is falsy. From there, you should be able to tell what caused it (the stack trace).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - it provides troubleshooting steps.